# send byte[] data over network stream socket. c#

Tags: c#, sockets, networkstream

i want to send string json over networkstream . code at client side

```
 using (var ns = new NetworkStream(socket))
{
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listCfile, Formatting.Indented);
 byte[] jsonbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
 byte[] jsonLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(jsonbytes.Length);
 ns.Write(jsonLength, 0, jsonLength.Length);
 ns.Write(jsonbytes, 0, jsonbytes.Length);
}
```

jsonbytes  was byte[988324]

At server side

```
 using (var ns = new NetworkStream(socket))
 {
 byte[] byDataLength = new byte[4];
ns.Read(byDataLength, 0, 4);
int jsonLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(byDataLength, 0);
byte[] byData = new byte[jsonLength];
ns.Read(byData, 0, jsonLength);
File.WriteAllBytes("E:\\json.txt",byData);
}
```

byData was byte[988324]

But byData i received isn't same as jsonbytes i sent.

i need some helps.

Update! some times it works. ByData received is same as jsonbytes i sent
Some times it doesn't work  :(

Comment: "it lose some data" is not a helpful description of the problem. Please elaborate.

Comment: From the client side is jsonLength sent before the actual data, to build a buffer at the server side to receive the json data?

Comment: @nura i think same as you , but i am beginner in c# and coding so you can give me some examples, thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using C# for both sides? how about architecture? is the client Mobile?

Comment: [NetworkStream.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx): "The Read operation reads as much data as is available, *up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter*". You're ignoring the return value from `Read` that tells you  how many bytes *were* read. There's no guarantee that calls to `Write` on one side are matched 1-1 with calls to `Read` on the other side. TCP is a stream of bytes. Not messages.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what should i do?

Comment: @vmphuong check and compare how much bytes read from read function first. Another possibility is that if you have tested using cross-platform as I mentioned before, you could have an archtiectural issue.

Comment: @Sean83. Both sides i use c# and PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using raw sockets to send and receive as well as using a memory stream and end-of-packet mechanism for unknown data lengths.

Below is a snippet of methods showing using raw sockets and buffering in a memory-stream till End-Of-Packet is detected.

```
    protected const int SIZE_RECEIVE_BUFFER = 1024; /// Receive buffer size
    protected const string EOF = "!#~*|"; /// End of packet string
    MemoryStream _msPacket = new MemoryStream(); /// Memory stream holding buffered data packets
    int _delmtPtr = 0; /// Ranking pointer to check for EOF 
    Socket _baseSocket;
    public event EventHandler OnReceived;

    // TODO: -
    // Add methods to connect or accept connections.
    // When data is send to receiver, send with the same EOF defined above.
    //
    //
    public void RegisterToReceive()
    {
        byte[] ReceiveBuffer = new byte[SIZE_RECEIVE_BUFFER];
        _baseSocket.BeginReceive
        (
            ReceiveBuffer,
            0,
            ReceiveBuffer.Length,
            SocketFlags.None,
            new AsyncCallback(onReceiveData),
            ReceiveBuffer
        );
    }
    private void onReceiveData(IAsyncResult async)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = (byte[])async.AsyncState;
            int bytesCtr = 0;
            try
            {
                if (_baseSocket != null)
                    bytesCtr = _baseSocket.EndReceive(async);
            }
            catch { }
            if (bytesCtr > 0)
                processReceivedData(buffer, bytesCtr);
            RegisterToReceive();
        }
        catch{ }
    }

    private void processReceivedData(byte[] buffer, int bufferLength)
    {
        byte[] eof = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EOF);
        int packetStart = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++)
        {
            if (buffer[i].Equals(eof[_delmtPtr]))
            {
                _delmtPtr++;
                if (_delmtPtr == eof.Length)
                {
                    var lenToWrite = i - packetStart - (_delmtPtr - 1);
                    byte[] packet = new byte[lenToWrite + (int)_msPacket.Position];

                    if (lenToWrite > 0)
                        _msPacket.Write(buffer, packetStart, lenToWrite);

                    packetStart = i + 1;
                    _msPacket.Position = 0;
                    _msPacket.Read(packet, 0, packet.Length);

                    try
                    {
                        if (OnReceived != null)
                            OnReceived(packet, EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                    catch { }
                    _msPacket.Position = 0;
                    _delmtPtr = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            { _delmtPtr = 0; }
        }
        if (packetStart < bufferLength)
            _msPacket.Write(buffer, packetStart, bufferLength - packetStart);
        if (_msPacket.Position == 0)
            _msPacket.SetLength(0);
    }
```

This can receive large length of data and is independent of length by the sender.

The methods above shows how to receive data only, so will have to include other methods for connect, accept, sending-data, etc on raw sockets.

Comment: thanks u very much but it's so complicated for me. There are other ways to do that. My data length is not unknown.